# Getting an entity from an associative List by 2 IDs

Tags: c#, linq, list, collections, find

I'm trying to use the Find method from a List or another one similar for that I want to do. I have 2 entities and an associative entity that has the IDs and the properties from each independent Entity. I want to find the object inside the associative list but for the combination from both entities IDs... something like this.

```
        //Entity1 attributes int ID, string NAME
        List<Entity1> listEntity1 = new List<Entity1>();
        listEntity1.Add(new Entity1(1, "A"));
        listEntity1.Add(new Entity1(2, "B"));
        listEntity1.Add(new Entity1(3, "C"));
        listEntity1.Add(new Entity1(4, "D"));
        listEntity1.Add(new Entity1(5, "E"));
        listEntity1.Add(new Entity1(6, "F"));

        //Entity2 attributes int ID, string NAME
        List<Entity2> listEntity2 = new List<Entity2>();
        listEntity2.Add(new Entity2(101, "AA"));
        listEntity2.Add(new Entity2(102, "BB"));
        listEntity2.Add(new Entity2(103, "CC"));
        listEntity2.Add(new Entity2(104, "DD"));
        listEntity2.Add(new Entity2(105, "EE"));
        listEntity2.Add(new Entity2(106, "FF"));            

        //Entity1_2 attributes int ID from Entity1, int ID from Entity2
        List<Entity1_2> listIntermediate = new List<Entity1_2>();
        listIntermediate.Add(new Entity1_2(1, 101));
        listIntermediate.Add(new Entity1_2(1, 103)); 
        listIntermediate.Add(new Entity1_2(2, 103)); 
        listIntermediate.Add(new Entity1_2(4, 101)); 
        listIntermediate.Add(new Entity1_2(4, 106)); 
        listIntermediate.Add(new Entity1_2(5, 106)); 
        Account

        Entity1_2 entity1_2 = listIntermediate.Find( by ID1 and ID2 ) and get the object Entity1_2 that has the info from both Entities
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine the keys:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Entity>();
dict.Add("1;A", new Entity(1, "A"));

Entity e;
If (dict.TryGetValue("1;A", out e)) {
    Use(e);
}
```

If you can integrate a method `public string GetKey()` in the entities that would be great.

```
var e = new Entity(1, "A");
dict.Add(e.GetKey(), e);
```

Also integrate a static method

```
public static string GetKey(int id, string name)
{
    return ...;
}
```

and then get the results like this

```
Entity e;
If (dict.TryGetValue(Entity.GetKey(1, "A"), out e)) {
    Use(e);
}
```

---

Note that a dictionary has much faster access times when retrieving by a key than a list. In big-O notation:

```
Dictionary<TKey, TElement>:   O(1)
List<T>:                      O(n)
```

---

If you need to keep your data in a list, find the information with:

```
Entity e = list
    .Where(x => x.ID == id && x.Name == name)
    .FirstOrDefault();

if (e != null) {
    Use(e);
}
```

Or use the `Find` method of `List<T>`

```
Entity e = list.Find(x => x.ID == id && x.Name == name);
if (e != null) {
    ...
}
```

It should be slightly faster than the LINQ approach with `Where`, but still `O(n)`.